# QuickBooks API - Retrieve transactions for all accounts

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

Is it possible to use the QuickBooks API to retrieve all transactions of all accounts defined in the chart of accounts, or of an individual account, and to filter by date range?

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi

Not sure if this would help: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/journalentry

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to get all transactions using any V2 api. To get all the transactions you can query individual entities like - Bill, Payment , Invoice etc

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue and the closest I have come is accessing a 'report' through the api like the general ledger report, and then filtering and parsing manually in c# code :( I feel your pain.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a report and then download the corresponding transactions:

http://developer.qbapi.com/Run-a-Report-on-Quickbooks-Online.aspx